# vbCompenent.Name property is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a macro to mass replace a named code module in every .xlsm file found in a selected folder. The code generally works, but I've run into a workbook where it consistently fails. In that workbook, I'm getting a subscript out of range error when I try to reference the named module (on 4th line below).

```
Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(fl.Path, False, False)
Set vbProj = wkbk.VBProject
With vbProj
   Set vbComp = vbProj.VBComponents(moduleToReplace)
   .VBComponents.Remove vbComp
   .VBComponents.Import (newModule)
End With
```

I have opened the workbook and verified that the module name in the moduleToReplace variable does exist.

I then added the following code to see what vbComponents are in the workbook.

```
For Each vbComp In vbProj.VBComponents
   Debug.Print vbComp.Name
Next
```

Looking at the immediate window after that runs, I see mostly blank lines.

How can a module have no name according to vbComponents when they are all named in the the editor?
Is there another way to reference module names that I can use instead?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where did you find the name of the sheet, in the Project Window, or among the sheet tabs of the workbook (window bottom), or both?